# Creating cronjobs with saltstack from a file

Tags: cron, jinja2, salt-stack

So I'm trying to import multiple cronjobs with a salt formula. The idea is to have a file for every server in the formula itself and import all cronjobs on state apply.

I checked the documentation, but all I could find was the salt.states.cron.file, which only works with a hosted file. In my case a template file in the formula itself should be used.

Is it even possible to implement multiple cronjobs from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Provides file.managed-like functionality (**templating**, etc.)

For example:

```yaml
crontab:
  cron.file:
    - name: salt://{{ tpldir }}/files/crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron tasks can be created and managed from an SLS file like so:

```
logs-cleanup-cron:
  cron.present:
    - name: '/usr/local/bin/log-cleanup.sh -r 31 -d /logs > /dev/null 2>&1'
    - user: root
    - minute: 55
    - hour: 23
    - daymonth: '*'
    - month: '*'
    - dayweek: '*'
    - identifier: 'CLEAN_LOGS'
```

Make sure you use a unique "identifier" in each block so you can manage each cron task.